# how to Use Then with angular JS function?

Tags: angularjs

```
app.controller('controller_name', function ($scope, $location, $auth, toastr, $http, CONFIG, $stateParams, $uibModal, $q, localStorageService, $anchorScroll, roundProgressService, $sce, calendarConfig, moment, $window, $rootScope) {

    $scope.a1(a, b, c, d, e).then(function(data){
        if (data.status == "OK") {
            angular.extend($scope.pets_list, response.data['pets_list']);
        }
    });

    $scope.a1 = function(a, b, c, d, e){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'url',
            data: {a: a, a: b},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

after using Then with functions i got an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do with the function, instead promise

```
scope.get = function(a, b, c, d, e) {

        var defered = $q.defer();

        $http.post('some_url', {a: a, a: b}).success(function(response){
            defered.resolve(response);
        }).error(function(response){
            defered.reject(response);
        });

        return defered.promise;
    };
};
var promise = scope.get(a, b, c, d, e);
promise.then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
},function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: if he just refactors, his example is perfectly fine. look my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at your console. Javascript uses hoisting, so you can define functions after calling them.

**Example hoisting**

```js
function foo() {
  myFunc();
  function myFunc(){
    console.log('foo');
  }
}

foo();
```

However in your example $scope is already defined. Calling a function on this object before you have defined it, should result in an error.

**Wrong Example**

```js
function foo(obj) {
  obj.myFunc(); // TypeError: obj.myFunc is not a function(…)
  obj.myFunc = function(){
    console.log('foo');
  }
}

var myObject = {};

foo(myObject);
```

Just use the function after it has been defined on `$scope` or if you do not need it on `$scope` stick to local variables.

**Local function**

```
app.controller('controller_name', function () {
    a1(a, b, c, d, e).then(function(data){
        // use result from promise
    });

   function a1(a, b, c, d, e){
     // logic
   };
});
```

**Use function from scope**

```
app.controller('controller_name', function () {
    $scope.a1 = a1; // hide implementation details on bottom

    $scope.a1(a, b, c, d, e).then(function(data){
        // use result from promise
    });

    function a1(a, b, c, d, e){
        // logic
    };
});
```

**General example with live code snippet**

```js
function foo(obj) {
  obj.myFunc = myFunc;
  obj.myFunc();
  
  function myFunc(){
    console.log('foo');
  }
}

var myObject = {};

foo(myObject);
```

Comment: still got an error Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at b.$scope.a1

Comment: did you declare it as shown in line 2? since it is declared there it is impossible to be undefined.